Physical intuition for the Minkowski space?
As the title suggests, I am looking for physical intuition to better understand the Minkowski metric.
My original motivation is trying to understand the necessity for distinguishing between co-variant and contra-varient indices.
For example, the quantity:
$$
A^{\mu}A^{\mu}
$$
Could still be computed in Minkowski space.
I am suspecting the necessity of $g_{\mu\nu}$ is to separate the space into two regions, one where $A^2>0$ and one where $A^2<0$. These corresponding to timelike and spacelike regions, which are further dependant on the specification of a constant $c$.
For example, I would interpret a metric
$$
m_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
in the Euclidian $[x,y]$ basis, to be a space where one dimension grows twice as fast as the other. Alternatively,
$$
m_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix} y & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
again in the Euclidian $[x,y]$ basis, would be a space where the $x$ dimension changes proportional to the location in the $y$ dimension.
How could the Minkowski space metric,
$$
m_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
now in the basis $[t,x]$, be interpreted?
As someone pointed out in the comments, this could be viewed as a mapping $t  \to -t$, but this doesn't seem to be the full picture.

Your example with $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is physically undistinguishable from the ordinary Euclidean plane space with matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Its just that whoever is in charge of placing the distance markings on the $x$ axis changed their mind and decided to place them twice as densely.

Contravariance and covariance can be physically motivated even purely within the Newtonian mechanics framework. It had simply been hidden from students.

Note that the components of the metric depend not only on the geometry of the space but also on the coordinate system. Your example is simply Minkowski spacetime with a different coordinate system. You have not changed anything at all. In order to specify a tensor, you need to supply both components and basis. Simply writing down components does not adequately specify a geometry.

@naturallyInconsistent how are contra and co variance naturally motivated in a Newtonian framework ?

@user10709800 They are mathematical concepts and do not arise out of physics.

@user10709800 If you want my absolutely naive take on it (which may be wrong), you have encountered all of these things in high school when they taught vectors and coordinates. The vectors are one kind of object, the coordinates are another. In linear algebra we pick a base of three linearly independent vectors and then we can describe an arbitrary vector using three coordinates that we use to form linear combinations of our base vectors with. One is called co-, the other contra-variant in "higher level physics". I could never remember which is which, though.

@VincentThacker It's actually the other way around. Almost all fundamental concepts of mathematics arose out of physical observations, starting with geometry and logic/set theory. Logic/set theory, which basically describes the behavior of "objects in baskets" then leads to arithmetic as we start counting the cardinality of sets. Geometry, including that on Riemannian manifolds certainly arouse out of practical concerns like geodesics (one of Gauss' job functions, I believe). Historically people probably didn't always notice that math was emulating and extrapolating "physics", though.

@FlatterMann That is not what modern mathematics is. It is axiomatic and does not depend on any physical considerations. The concept of "covariance" and "contravariance" is a mathematical one.

@VincentThacker It doesn't matter "what modern mathematics is". It uses rules (like propositional logic) that were derived from the behavior of classical objects. The history of mathematics starts with observations of nature that are then being abstracted. I will go as far as to predict that mathematics in the 21st century will have an epiphany: it wasted a lot of time on extrapolating classical sets that do not actually exist in nature and it will have to start over from scratch with rules based on quantum theory. If you haven't heard this before, then you heard it from me.

@FlatterMann I neither understand what you mean nor see how it has any relevance here. The fact is that mathematics today is detached from the physical world. Abstract mathematics is a subject in its own right. The concept of "covariance" and "contravariance" is a mathematical one, from linear algebra to be specific. Physics uses mathematics to model the universe and that is only part of it. It is not necessary for all areas of mathematics to follow the physical world and it is indeed far from it. Or else things such as Banach-Tarski wouldn't exist.

@VincentThacker The usual inference rules of mathematics are the behavior of objects in baskets. I don't know how that is "detached" from the physical world. Covariant and contravariant quantities are the behaviors of rulers. Metric theories would be completely useless if they wouldn't represent measurement prescriptions. There are areas of mathematics that are completely detached. Yes, Banach-Tarski is one of them. That doesn't mean that all of it is.

@FlatterMann I have already said it multiple times. Contravariance and covariance are concepts from linear algebra: the behavior of tensors under change of basis. The mathematical concept exists independently of the motivations for its use in physics.

@VincentThacker Math never existed independently of physics because the human mind doesn't exist independently of physics. Most of mathematics hugs physical observations extremely closely. That's the reason why math works for physicists. Much of it is idealized classical physics. The mathematicians have, so far, not even caught up with quantum mechanics. Once they do, math will change completely.

@FlatterMann "Most of mathematics hugs physical observations extremely closely" That may have been the case a long time ago but today it is simply false for reasons explained in my previous comments. I see no point in repeating them again. Mathematical physics is just one small part of mathematics. The mathematical concepts can be defined and constructed independently of physics.

@VincentThacker Pretty much all the central notions in set theory, logic, arithmetic, algebra, geometry, topology and calculus are taken from classical physics. If you strip that away, what is left of mathematics?

@FlatterMann Your assertion is again simply wrong. Physical intuition/considerations does not get anywhere in mathematics - just check out the Weierstrass function. The same goes for anything involving infinity, which is abundant in mathematics. You still don't seem to have gotten the message so this will be my last comment.

@VincentThacker We call that "white noise" in physics and we are dealing with it in the frequency domain.

I don’t think that people can give you intuition. Intuition is something that you develop through experience. Since we basically live non-relativistic lives, such experience is gained through working problems, drawing spacetime diagrams, and so forth.
That said, here is how I think of things.
First, the motivation: experimentally we see that the speed of light is frame invariant. This means that if $$-c^2 dt^2+ dx^2+dy^2+dz^2= 0$$ then $$-c^2 dt’^2+ dx’^2+dy’^2+dz’^2=0$$ We notice that this looks a lot like the Pythagorean theorem except that time is also a part of it. So we make an intuitive leap that maybe space and time are part of a united spacetime and the quantity is a sort of spacetime “distance” $$-c^2 dt^2+ dx^2+dy^2+dz^2=ds^2$$
With that leap, we notice that the above quantity has a lot of desirable properties:

it has positive (spacelike) $ds^2$ values which are measured by rulers and negative (timelike) $ds^2$ values measured by clocks.
the timelike values are separated into future and past loci that are frame invariant. This gives an invariant causal structure to time. There is no similar separation in spacelike loci.
it has 0 (null or lightlike) $ds^2$ values which all frames agree on.
Newton’s first law is easily represented by straight lines in this spacetime. The transform between inertial frames is an affine transform.

For me, these desirable properties are enough to give some intuition. By understanding why we like this sort of structure, I understand how it behaves a little.
The distinction between covariant and contravariant quantities is not strong in flat (Minkowski) spacetime. You do need it in curved spacetime.
But the general meaning is not particularly illuminating: at each point your coordinates can be considered to establish a set of basis vectors or a set of basis planes perpendicular to those vectors. The contravariant components are projections onto the vectors and the covariant components are projections onto this planes. They don’t really form different physical quantities, but different ways of representing the same quantity. I.e. referencing the basis vectors or the basis planes.
Anyway, intuition is built by experience. So just get busy solving problems and actually using them.
